# How can a I limit the possibility of calling the buttonTapped function and selecting just three buttons?

Tags: swift, uibutton

Is it possible to limit the selection of buttons to just three buttons at the same time? I want users to select just 3 character traits. Right now my code is set-up in a way that tapping the button changes the image to a highlighted image. Giving the impression it is selected. I want only three buttons to be selected at once.

```
import UIKit

class CharacteristicsViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var confidenceButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var humbleButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var creativeButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var athleticButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var loyalButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var intelligenceButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var punctualButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var kindButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var braveButton: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //HIDE/SHOW NAVIGATION BAR
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

    //1. CONFIDENCE BUTTON SETTINGS
    confidenceButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "confidentnor"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    confidenceButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "confidenthigh"), for: UIControlState.selected)
    confidenceButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    //2. HUMBLE BUTTON SETTINGS
    humbleButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "humblenor"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    humbleButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "humblehigh"), for: UIControlState.selected)
    humbleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    //3. CREATIVE BUTTON SETTINGS
    creativeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "creativenor"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    creativeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "creativehigh"), for: UIControlState.selected)
    creativeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    //4. ATHLETIC BUTTON SETTINGS
    athleticButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "athleticnor"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    athleticButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "athletichigh"), for: UIControlState.selected)
    athleticButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    //5. LOYAL BUTTON SETTINGS
    loyalButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "loyalnor"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    loyalButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "loyalhigh"), for: UIControlState.selected)
    loyalButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    //6. INTELLIGENT BUTTON SETTINGS
    intelligenceButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "intelligentnor"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    intelligenceButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "intelligenthigh"), for: UIControlState.selected)
    intelligenceButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    //7. PUNCTUAL BUTTON SETTINGS
    punctualButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "punctualnor"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    punctualButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "punctualhigh"), for: UIControlState.selected)
    punctualButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    //8. KIND BUTTON SETTINGS
    kindButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "kindnor"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    kindButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "kindhigh"), for: UIControlState.selected)
    kindButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    //9. BRAVE BUTTON SETTINGS
    braveButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "bravenor"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    braveButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "bravehigh"), for: UIControlState.selected)
    braveButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

}

//BUTTON HIGHLIGHT FUNCTION
func buttonTapped(sender:UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected; }


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()


}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enclose your buttons inside a `UIView`, you can use this view's subviews to iterate through the buttons which will make things a little easier. There's no need to make every button an outlet however, if you choose not to, you'll have to set the `.normal` and `.selected` images in the storyboard.

Once you have a view that contains only the buttons, you can create a computed property that returns a mapped array of `UIButton` as well as a property that tells you how many buttons are currently selected.

```
// MARK: Outlets

@IBOutlet weak var traitButtonsView: UIView?

// MARK: Properties

var traitsSelected: Int {
    return traitButtons.filter { $0.isSelected }.count
}
var traitButtons: [UIButton] {
    return traitButtonsView?.subviews.flatMap { $0 as? UIButton } ?? []
}

// MARK: Actions

func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    if traitsSelected < 3 || sender.isSelected {
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep some kind of counter that increments and decrements every time buttons are tapped.

```
var counter = 0;

func buttonTapped(sender:UIButton) { 
    if sender.isSelected {
        counter += 1
    }
    else {
        counter -= 1
    }

    if counter > 3 {
        return;
    }
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected;
}
```